# Following a program's execution

Tags: python, c, debugging, gdb

I'm looking to 'watch' a program as it executes. I want to, for example, keep track of a program's stack pointer as it changes through execution. I've been looking at scripting GDB with python but the solutions to this are very buggy - I've been unsuccessful thus far at installing PythonGDB. If anyone has any solutions / recommendations as to how to approach this problem I would be very grateful.

EDIT: I should have mentioned, I'm looking to record these values - ideally automatically - to be able to review them afterwards. I understand GDB allows me to step through the program and view the each state but I want to automate this process to be able to 'watch' how a particular values (such as the SP) change over time.

Comment: You might find the [Online Python Tutor program visualizer](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#) interesting. Although I suppose it's only good for programs that can fit into a text box.

Answer (score 1):

This is a SystemTap solution for a test program with debugging information:

First a test C++ program (built with g++ -g main.cpp):

```
>cat main.cpp

void a()
{
   char arr[12800];
}


void b()
{
   char arr[1280];
   a();
}


void c()
{
   char arr[128];
   b();
}

int main()
{
   char arr[12];
   c();
   return 0;
}
```

Then a SystemTap script:

```
>cat measure_f.stp
probe process("a.out").function("*")
{
  printf("%-10s: rbp:%x, rsp:%x, %d\n", probefunc(), register("rbp"), register("rsp"), register("rbp") - register("rsp"))
}
```

Then a test itself:

```
>sudo stap measure_f.stp -c ./a.out
main      : rbp:7fffd3707a10, rsp:7fffd3707a00, 16
c         : rbp:7fffd37079f0, rsp:7fffd3707970, 128
b         : rbp:7fffd3707960, rsp:7fffd3707460, 1280
a         : rbp:7fffd3707450, rsp:7fffd37042c8, 12680
```

Answer (score 0):

ubiQ,

I've always used IDLE for debugging. Do a google search for it. Hope this helps, if not, let me know!

Comment: Hi Xanesis, I've updated my original post to reflect this but what i'm after is an ability to record particular values automatically (such as the SP) as the program executes, this will allow me to view how the state of these values changes over time afterwards. Does IDLE have this kind of capability?

Comment: I do believe so, at any time, it gives you a list of all if the variables and their values in the program. Hope this helps!