# How can I trace all local function calls and exits, and record it to a file to review

Tags: c, linux, debugging, call, trace

I want to trace a C program under Linux, and record all function calls and returns in a format of tree.
For example, the source code:

```
void a ()
{
    printf("a\n");
}
void b ()
{
    printf("b\n");
}

void c ()
{
    a();
    b();
}

int main()
{
    a();
    b();
    c();
}
```

And I want a output like the following:

```
call main
    call a
    exit a
    call b
    exit b
    call c
        call a
        exit a
        call b
        exit b
    exit c
exit main
```

It is a idealistic output. I just want to get all the process of local function calls and returns, so the similar output is also welcome.

Comment: Well use `printf` to track the entry and exit out of functions (The constructor/destructor concept of C++). To print in file use `fprintf`

Comment: please check this link.. it might be helpful.



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374005/how-to-trace-function-call-in-c

Comment: It is a big project, so it's hard to inject fprintf statements to all the functions manually.  Is there any tools to help me?

Comment: You could probably find useful ltrace. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html for tracing the calls but I didn't see if you can trace the exits.

Comment: SystemTap has what you need https://sourceware.org/systemtap/tutorial/Tracing.html#SECTION00032000000000000000. The only thing that can cause a problem is that your project can be too big to trace it with SystemTap. Once I answered more or less the same quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764462/following-a-programs-execution

Answer (score 2):

gcc -finstrument-functions does my job

Answer (score 0):

To produce such an output by modifying code, try something like this (not optimized but does the job):

```
size_t indent;

#define ENTER_FUNC(function_name)                     \
    indent++;                                         \
    for(size_t i=0; i<indent; i++) printf("\t");      \
    printf("Call %s\n", function_name);

#define EXIT_FUNC(function_name)                     \
    for(size_t i=0; i<indent; i++) printf("\t");     \
    printf("Exit %s\n", function_name);              \
    indent--;
```

Call `ENTER_FUNC` at the beginning of each function to trace and `EXIT_FUNC` prior to any `return`.
You can also enrich the macro to write in a log file.

Otherwise there are some profiling tools like [gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/) for [example](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html)

Comment: Thanks very much! It is a big project, so it's hard to inject ENTER_FUNC statements to all the functions manually. Is there any tools to help me to insert the ENTER_FUNC to all the functions ?

Comment: Well, if you know Python for instance you could write a script to do the job. It can also be (carefully) done in an editor like Vim with the proper search & replace command. For example: wherever there is a `return [whatever];` insert `EXIT_FUNC`.
Also note that if you have a big program with a lot of calls, these macros will deeply affect your performances. And they're not protected against competitive calls (threads, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Use cflow would be a good choice as well. The information of cflow could be found in gnu website,
https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/

Below is an example of cflow,

```
$ cflow foo.c cl.12.*.c
main() <int main (void) at foo.c:18>:
    foo_trivial_questions() <void foo_trivial_questions (void) at foo.c:13>:
        foo_cl_12_test() <void foo_cl_12_test (void) at cl.12.IntegertoRoman.c:32>:
            foo() <void foo (int n) at cl.12.IntegertoRoman.c:24>:
                intToRoman() <char *intToRoman (int num) at cl.12.IntegertoRoman.c:3>:
                    malloc()
                    strcat()
                printf()
                free()
```